# preg_match problem

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm trying to get some stuff from a string in php. In RegexBuddy and Regular expression tester (firefox addon) it works good, but php gives me the following:

> Warning: preg_match()
>   [function.preg-match]: Compilation
>   failed: unmatched parentheses at
>   offset 34 in
>   D:\path\example.php
>   on line 62

my pattern is `"/.{4}_tmp\\([A-Za-z0-9.\\]*)\(([0-9]*)\) : (.*)/i"`

an example string: `C:\Temp\browseide\projects\32\821C_tmp\SourceFiles\main.c(8) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'for'`

what RegexBuddy gets:

```
821C_tmp\SourceFiles\main.c(8) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'for'
Group 1:    SourceFiles\main.c
Group 2:    8
Group 3:    error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'for'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the backslashes in the PHP string:

```
"/.{4}_tmp\\\\([A-Za-z0-9.\\\\]*)\\(([0-9]*)\\) : (.*)/i"
```

Comment: Doubling up the ` \\ ` at the end isn't necessary - PHP has no special `\(` or `\)` so it doesn't need to be escaped... Doesn't hurt either, just thought it worth mentioning.

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the back-slash again, once PHP string parses that string you end up with:

```
/.{4}_tmp\([A-Za-z0-9.\]*)\(([0-9]*)\) : (.*)/i
```

Try `echo "/.{4}_tmp\\([A-Za-z0-9.\\]*)\(([0-9]*)\) : (.*)/i";`

You should have `\\\\` inside your double quotes if you want a `\\` in the pattern